# JS and PHP variable don't show good

Tags: javascript, php, variables, if-statement

If this was in asks, sorry for that, but I want to speed help, thanks!

Do you have suggestions for result this ? Because when I do this it show last $name, it doesn't work.

JavaScript:

```
var name = 'Test';
if(name === 'Test'){
<?php $name = "Test"; ?>
} else {
<?php $name = "Error"; ?>
}
```

I have click function and when I click I check ID of object, but after this I want check this id is good e.g. (if(id === 'content')) and show good alert, when i checked it.

Comment: You can't embed php in JS. You can pass JS data to php with AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

This is your server-side code, which will execute exactly once when the page is requested:

```
$name = "Test";
$name = "Error";
```

After this code executes, `$name` will be `"Error"`.  Every time.

This is your client-side code, which will execute exactly once when the page renders in the browser:

```
var name = 'Test';
if(name === 'Test'){

} else {

}
```

After this code executes, `name` will be `'Test'`.  Every time.

You're trying to mix server-side code and client-side code.  They don't mix like that.  They execute on two completely different platforms at two completely different times in two completely different contexts.  Whatever you're trying to do (which we don't know), this isn't how you do it.

Answer (score 0):

The way you wrote it isn't going to work. First of all PHP is executed before the JavaScript is parsed. In your code you set a variable inside PHP, so nothing actually happens. If you want something written on the page use `echo` or `print`.

What I think you want is to send a variable to PHP. For this you need a form or an Ajax-call.

If you want it the other way around, set a JavaScript variable based upon a PHP value you need to use JSON notification.

Comment: Do you have idea, how it's should look ?

Answer (score -1):

The only way I could even think of doing this would be:

```
<script>
var name = 'Test';
if(name === 'Test'){
</script>
<?php $name = "Test"; ?>
<script>
} else {
</script>
<?php $name = "Error"; ?>
<script>
}
</script>
```

Comment: This would throw a bunch of syntax errors with missing `}`.